# access.log awk command to view bandwidth out per virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

My access log lists multiple domains.

What awk command could I use to view each domain's bandwidth individually?

It would also be nice to specify a date range.

Comment: can you pastebin a part of that log?

Comment: sure, http://pastebin.com/WAE4ePF6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{split($0,a," "); values[a[1]]=values[a[1]]$11","}END {for (i in values) {print i" "values[i]}}' awk_log.txt | awk -F ',| ' '{s=0; for(i=2; i<=NF;i++) s=s+$i; print $1 " Incomming Traf: "  s/1024 "Kbs"}'
```

Output:

```
site2.com:80 Incomming Traf: 47.0508Kbs
site1.com:80 Incomming Traf: 6.33105Kbs
```

I multiplied your sample by 3 times.

Comment: your output is wrong, not by domain, but per REMOTE_ADDR (client ip)

Comment: Yeah. From mine. I am male